# How do you call a function from one class and apply it to another function from a different class in c++?

Tags: c++, oop, methods

## Problem

I am trying to call a function from a different class and apply it to a similar function to another class.

#### Specifics of the Problem

I have a class called User and I have a function called RelationType ComparedTo(User* aUser) const;. This function must call a function from a different class called DateType and that function is called RelationType ComparedTo(DateType someDate);.

## Code

This is my code for the problem. I probably have something wrong somewhere else but I haven't received errors yet so I am hoping I am right.

#### DateType.h

RelationType ComparedTo(DateType someDate); is at the bottom of public.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
//Declare a class to represent the Date ADT
enum RelationType { LESS, EQUAL, GREATER };

class DateType
{
public:
    DateType();
    void Initialize(int newMonth, int newDat, int newYear);
    int GetMonth() const;               //returns month
    int GetYear() const;                //returns year
    int GetDay() const;                 //returns day
    string GetMonthAsString() const;        //returns month as string
    DateType Adjust(int daysAway) const;
    RelationType ComparedTo(DateType someDate) const;
private:
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};
```

#### DateType.cpp

RelationType DateType::ComparedTo(DateType someDate) const is the second to last function.

```
#include "DateType.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

DateType::DateType()
{
    year = 1980;
    month = 1;
    day = 1;
}
//Number of days in each month
static int daysInMonth[] = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

//Names of months
static string conversionTable[] = { "Error", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
                                    "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

void DateType::Initialize(int newMonth, int newDay, int newYear)
/*
    Post: If newMonth, newDay, and newYear represent a valid date, 
        year is set to newYear;
        month is set to newMonth;
        day is set to newDay;
        otherwise a string exception is thrown, stating the first
        incorrect parameter.
*/
{
    if (newMonth < 1 || newMonth > 12)
        throw string("Month is invalid");
    else if (newDay < 1 || newDay > daysInMonth[newMonth])
        throw string("Day is invalid");
    else if (newYear < 1600)
        throw string("Year is invalid");
    year = newYear;
    month = newMonth;
    day = newDay;
}

int DateType::GetMonth() const
{
    return month;
}

string DateType::GetMonthAsString() const
{
    return conversionTable[month];
}

int DateType::GetYear() const
{
    return year;
}

int DateType::GetDay() const
{
    return day;
}

RelationType DateType::ComparedTo(DateType someDate) const
/*
    Pre: Self and aDate have been initialized.
    Post: Function Value = LESS, if self comes before aDate
                         = EQUAL, if self is the same as aDate
                         = GREATER, is self comes after aDate
*/
{
    if (year < aDate.year)
        return LESS;
    else if (year > aDate.year)
        return GREATER;
    else if (month < aDate.month)
        return LESS;
    else if (month > aDate.month)
        return GREATER;
    else if (day < aDate.day)
        return LESS;
    else if (day > aDate.day)
        return GREATER;
    else
        return EQUAL;
}

DateType DateType::Adjust(int daysAway) const
/*
    Pre: Self has been initialized
    Post: Function value = newDate daysAway from self
*/
{
    int newDay = day + daysAway;
    int newMonth = month;
    int newYear = year;
    bool finished = false;
    int daysInThisMonth;
    DateType returnDate;
    while (!finished)
    {
        daysInThisMonth = daysInMonth[newMonth];
        if (newMonth == 2)
            if (((newYear % 4 == 0) && !(newYear % 100 == 0)) || (newYear % 400 == 0))
                daysInThisMonth++;
        if (newDay <= daysInThisMonth)
            finished = true;
        else
        {
            newDay = newDay - daysInThisMonth;
            newMonth = (newMonth % 12) + 1;
            if (newMonth == 1)
                newYear++;
        }
    }

    returnDate.Initialize(newMonth, newDay, newYear);
    return returnDate;
}
```

#### User.h

RelationType ComparedTo(User* aUser) const; is the second function.

```
#include "DateType.h"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum RelationType { LESS, EQUAL, GREATER };

class User
{
public:
    User();
    void Initialize(char firstName[6], char lastName[6], DateType date);
    RelationType ComparedTo(User* aUser) const;
    string ToString();
    DateType getDateOfBirth();
    string getFirstName();
private:
    char fName[6];
    char lName[6];
    DateType dateOfBirth;
};
```

#### User.cpp

This part of the code is incomplete and may have errors but I have not received any notification of any errors except for the compared to function so I hope I am right with the other parts of the code. RelationType User::ComparedTo(User* aUser) const is at the bottom of the code.

```
#include "User.h"
#include "DateType.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

User::User()
{
    string fName = "none";
    string lName = "none";
    DateType dateOfbirth;
}

void User::Initialize(char firstName[6], char lastName[6], DateType date)
{
    if (firstName[6] > 6 || firstName[6] < 1)
        throw string("First name is invalid");
    else if (lastName[6] > 6 || lastName[6] < 1)
        throw string("Last name is invalid");
    fName[6] = firstName[6];
    lName[6] = lastName[6];
    dateOfBirth = date;
}

DateType User::getDateOfBirth()
{
    return dateOfBirth;
}

RelationType User::ComparedTo(User* aUser) const //come back to this if I have a problem
{
    DateType aDate;
    aDate = dateOfBirth;
    dateOfBirth.ComparedTo(DateType someDate); //I might be close idk
    

    

}
```

## User.cpp Problem

As you can see I do not know how to call for the ComparedTo(DateType someDate) function. My syntax and logic for RelationType User::ComparedTo(User* aUser) const is all messed up. I have tried looking up friends of classes to see if that would work but the only thing that makes sense to me is this dot. Am I missing something very simple?

## Disclaimer

This is my first time asking a question here. Forgive me if I make the question confusing to understand.

Comment: 1) `DateType::ComparedTo` The argument is declared as `someDate` but the code uses `aDate` which is not defined. 2) `User::ComparedTo` Use `dateOfBirth.ComparedTo(aUser->dateOfBirth)` to compare the dates. 3) `fName[6] = firstName[6];` This is wrong because it overruns the buffer, and even if it didn't it would still copy one single character, not the entire array.

Comment: Feel free to remove all the functions not needed for your issue. It removes a lot of noise and helps people focus on one issue. It would also remove the need to tell us how to find the functions of interest, as only the functions of interest would remain.